# Php mysql pdo query: fill up variable with query result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I have a website to easily generate ProFTPD users. And now, I am securing my website against sql injection attacks, to do that I am changing all mysqli queries to pdo queries with prepared statements.

But I still couldn't find out, how to save sql query results in variable.

```
.
.
.

username=$_POST['username'];

.
.
.

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='db', 'root', 'PW');
$query1= $pdo->prepare('select * from users where userid=:username');
$query1->execute(array('username' => $username));

foreach($query1 as $row)
{
 $result= $row->userid;
}


if($result == $username)
{
 echo "Username is already taken";
}
```

When I run this code, the variable $result is emtpy.

I hope somebody could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='db', 'root', 'PW');` Remove the `'` before `db`

Comment: I posted a complete example, that might help you in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PDOStatement::fetch http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

Even if you already have a solution, you might find helpful a complete example of using PDO prepared statements together with exception handling:

**Notes:**

- Don't fetch all fields, but just `userid`. Limit fetching to only one record.
- Always use [exception handling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to catch and immediately handle exceptions.
- Always use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid MySQL injection.
- The items in the fetched data array are addressed as normal array items.
- "functions.php" contains all needed functions and is included in "index.php". I didn't give you an OOP code, but you should implement one instead of using plain functions. My code serves as starting point for you.

---

### PDO prepared statements and exception handling in PHP:

#### index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'functions.php';

/*
 * ----------------
 * Database configs
 * ----------------
 */

define('MYSQL_HOST', '...');
define('MYSQL_PORT', '3306');
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', '...');
define('MYSQL_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('MYSQL_USERNAME', '...');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '...');

/*
 * -------------------------
 * Start program
 * -------------------------
 */

// Activate error reporting (only on development).
activateErrorReporting();

try {
    // Validate user name.
    if (!isset($_POST['username'])) {
        throw new Exception('No user name provided!');
    }

    // Get user name.
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    // Create db connection.
    $connection = createConnection(
            MYSQL_HOST
            , MYSQL_DATABASE
            , MYSQL_USERNAME
            , MYSQL_PASSWORD
            , MYSQL_PORT
            , MYSQL_CHARSET
    );

    // Define sql statement.
    $sql = 'SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = :username LIMIT 1';

    // Prepare and check sql statement (returns PDO statement).
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement) {
        throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
    }

    // Bind values to sql statement parameters.
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username, getInputParameterDataType($username));

    // Execute and check PDO statement.
    if (!$statement->execute()) {
        throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
    }

    // Fetch person details.
    $fetchedData = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$fetchedData) {
        throw new Exception('Fetching data failed!');
    }

    closeConnection($connection);
} catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
    // On development.
    printData($pdoException, TRUE);

    // On production.
    // echo $pdoException->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    // On development.
    printData($exception, TRUE);

    // On production.
    // echo $exception->getMessage();
    exit();
}

// For testing purposes.
printData($fetchedData, TRUE);

if (count($fetchedData) > 0) {
    echo 'Username is already taken';
}
```

#### functions.php:

```
<?php

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------
 * Data access functions
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */

/**
 * Create a new db connection.
 * 
 * @param string $host Host.
 * @param string $dbname Database name.
 * @param string $username Username.
 * @param string $password Password.
 * @param string $port [optional] Port.
 * @param array $charset [optional] Character set.
 * @param array $options [optional] Driver options.
 * @return PDO Db connection.
 */
function createConnection($host, $dbname, $username, $password, $port = '3306', $charset = 'utf8', $options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
)) {
    $dsn = getDsn($host, $dbname, $port, $charset);
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $connection->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
    return $connection;
}

/**
 * Create a mysql DSN string.
 * 
 * @param string $host Host.
 * @param string $dbname Database name.
 * @param string $port [optional] Port.
 * @param array $charset [optional] Character set.
 * @return string DSN string.
 */
function getDsn($host, $dbname, $port = '3306', $charset = 'utf8') {
    $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s'
            , $host
            , $port
            , $dbname
            , $charset
    );
    return $dsn;
}

/**
 * Close a db connection.
 * 
 * @param PDO $connection Db connection.
 * @return void
 */
function closeConnection($connection) {
    $connection = NULL;
}

/**
 * Get the data type of a binding value.
 * 
 * @param mixed $value Binding value.
 * @return mixed Data type of the binding value.
 */
function getInputParameterDataType($value) {
    $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    if (is_int($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    }
    return $dataType;
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------
 * Print functions
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */

/**
 * Print data on screen.
 * 
 * @param mixed $data Data to print.
 * @param bool $preformatted Print preformatted if TRUE, print normal otherwise.
 * @return void
 */
function printData($data, $preformatted = FALSE) {
    if ($preformatted) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
    } else {
        echo $data;
    }
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------
 * Error reporting functions
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */

/**
 * Toggle error reporting.
 * 
 * @param integer $level Error level.
 * @param bool $display_errors Display errors if TRUE, hide them otherwise.
 * @return void
 */
function activateErrorReporting($level = E_ALL, $display_errors = TRUE) {
    error_reporting($level);
    ini_set('display_errors', ($display_errors ? 1 : 0));
}
```

Comment: Thank you rellay much for your helpful and detailed answer.

Comment: I already check the user's input with if/else.
E.g. if($username="") { echo "Missing arguments";}
Is there any difference from if/else and try/catch?

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, if-else and try-catch are two different things. Try-catch is used to catch exceptions and to handle them. A lot of PHP commands/statements are throwing exceptions in case something go wrong. If you don't catch them with `catch`, your program stops completely as if an error was raised. The exceptions are actually errors. Comparing with the PHP errors they can be handled elegantly. The only chance is to catch these exceptions and handle them properly. Take an example without try-catch: open a db connection with a false db name and see what happens...

Comment: Then apply the try-catch block, as I did, and see then. If-else is just a normal conditional construct, having nothing to do with errors/exceptions per se. I recommend you to search in web and learn all that you can about errors/exception handling in PHP. It's a very important part, that you should take into consideration, as developer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and effort. I am going to have a look at the excpetion handeling in php.

Comment: @Wubi With pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Try by change

```
$query1= $pdo->prepare('select * from users where userid=:username');
```

to

```
$query1= $pdo->query('select * from users where userid=:username');
```

access data as follows

```
foreach($query1 as $row)
{
 $result= $row['userid'];
}
```