# Error: Call to a member function fetch() on array PDO not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have seen quit a few similar questions, but none of the solutions for them worked for me so I am asking this.

This is the code:-

```
                $sql = "SELECT sifra, IDartikli
                        FROM {$this->prefix}artikli
                        WHERE IDartikli = {$artikel_id};";
                 echo "$sql";
                $stmt = $this -> db -> execute($sql);
                print_r($stmt);
                $table = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
                //$table = $stmt;
                 // trenutne podatke vstavimo v tabelo artikli_stari
                $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->prefix}artikli_stari
                        (EAN,
                        IDartikli)
                        VALUES('{$table['sifra']}',
                        '{$table['IDartikli']}');";
                $stmt = $this -> db ->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
```

I get the error here `$table = $stmt->fetch()`;
I tried the sql in phpmyadmin and it works fine there, and the function `print_r($stmt);` gets me this

```
Array
(
    [status] => OK
    [id] => 
    [count] => 
)
```

I do not know why it is not executing. DB class is required and works for the other queries in the same file which are like this
`$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and they work correctly. I also tried `PHP` lint which can't find an error in my code.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and you seem to be missing the point of prepared statements - incidentally the first statement `$stmt = $this -> db -> execute($sql);` is not `prepared` ~ was it supposed to be?

Comment: Hi. Have you found your solution?

Comment: I simply did it the long way 
$stmt = $database->connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':articleId' => $artikel_id]);

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand how `execute()` works: You need to prepare a statement and then you pass an array with the placeholders values as the parameter. You don't pass an sql string.

So your first query should look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT sifra, IDartikli
                    FROM {$this->prefix}artikli
                    WHERE IDartikli = :articleId;";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':articleId' => $artikel_id]);
```

And your table name should be checked against a white-list if it comes from an unknown source as you cannot prepare a table name.

Comment: Actually execute is a function in my DB class which does this

$this -> stmt = $this -> connection -> prepare($sql);

So I do prepare the statement, but it is in elsewhere

Comment: @Noon We cannot debug what we cannot see. And you don't prepare anything as the values are injected in the query directly.

Answer (score 0):

- The function `execute()` takes the values for the statement markers
  as arguments. See: [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).
- Before `PDOStatement::execute` you must call `PDO::prepare`, passing the sql statement as argument.
- Always use markers for passing the values to the [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).
- Don't ever use semicolons (;) as part of sql statements.
- But use semicolon after each PHP statement (you forgot it after `$table = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`) :-)
- Always use the [prepared statements together with exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183736/php-mysql-pdo-query-fill-up-variable-with-query-result/45184628#45184628) (that's a complete answer posted by me today).

Good luck!

```
$sql = "SELECT sifra, IDartikli
        FROM {$this->prefix}artikli
        WHERE IDartikli = :artikel_id";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':artikel_id' => $artikel_id,
));

$table = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sifra = $table['sifra'];
$IDartikli = $table['IDartikli'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->prefix}artikli_stari (
            EAN,
            IDartikli
        ) VALUES (
            ':sifra',
            ':IDartikli'
        )";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':sifra' => $sifra,
    ':IDartikli' => $IDartikli,
));
//...
```